# How to detect whether an dom element has loaded on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, single-page-application, mutation-observers

I have a single page application where a div with a class "abc" is getting loaded dynamically. I want to run a script only after that particular element and all its children have been loaded in the DOM. I don't want to use a timer which calls the function again and again. How do I go about this. This is probably related to mutation observer but I am not understanding how to use that.

Comment: Are you using Knockout to load the div?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example with mutation observer

```
var target = document.querySelector('.class');

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        console.log(mutation.type);
    });
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true }

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);
```

So for each mutation of the target element 
this code `console.log(mutation.type);`
will be execute

Comment: the target element is the one which is getting added dynamically right?

Comment: The `target` should be the container element of `.abc` or, for maximum coverage and robustness, `document`. Then you'll have to enumerate the added nodes and see if `.abc` was added. Or you can simply check it in the entire document via the superfast document.getElementsByClassName. See also [How to change the HTML content as it's loading on the page](//stackoverflow.com/a/39334319)

Comment: You can observe parent off this element, block where you add this element for instance

Answer (score -2):

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', '.abc', function() {

});
```

This will wait until the DOM element is ready and then run your code.

Comment: Bad advice: mutation events DOMxxxx are deprecated for many years.